# how to get OutputStream

Tags: scala, lift

I want to get an image from a response but I don't know how to get the OutputStream.

I know in jsp, it is:

```
 response.getOutputStream()
```

but what is it in liftweb ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your questions doesn't make sense, I think you need to provide some more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lift, there are very few cases (none that I can think of) where you need the outputStream.

If you are returning a composed HTML page, Lift's templating system takes care of collecting the HTML to send back to the browser.

If you are returning a response from a web service, you return a subclass of LiftResponse from your handler function, for example: XmlResponse(bar)

If you are streaming a file or something else, there's a special case LiftResponse: StreamingResponse

Please bring your question to the Lift community http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/topics?hl=en and we can have a conversation about what your goal is and how to achieve that goal.

Thanks!